# Is checking SDK_INT enough or is lazy loading needed for using newer android APIs ? Why?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-compatibility

Code such as :

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        ed.apply();
    else ed.commit();
```

produces a warning in Froyo :

> 04-27 03:40:35.025: W/dalvikvm(3138): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 219: Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;.apply ()V

But I understand that in older devices this would be a RuntimeError which would abort the application (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495007/verifyerror-deploying-on-api-1-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290957/281545)).

So is this way of conditionally calling new API (methods) safe in API 8 (Froyo) and above or there are cases where lazy loading is still needed ?

What changes on Dalvik made this possible ?

**Related**

- [Android recommended way of safely supporting newer apis has error if the class implements a newer interface. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103902/android-recommended-way-of-safely-supporting-newer-apis-has-error-if-the-class-i)
- [Android solving compatibility with SDK_INT hack; is this ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183461/android-solving-compatibility-with-sdk-int-hack-is-this-ok)
- [Android Dalvik Verification in Eclair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265459/android-dalvik-verification-in-eclair)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> produces a warning in Froyo

This is perfectly normal.

> But I understand that in older devices this would be a RuntimeError which would abort the application

For Android 1.x, yes.

> So is this way of conditionally calling new API (methods) safe in API 8 (Froyo) and above

Yes.

> What changes on Dalvik made this possible ?

It no longer "fails fast" when encountering an unidentified symbol, but instead waits to try again to resolve it when the statement is executed. By checking `SDK_INT` and ensure that the statement is not executed, you don't crash.

Comment: The change that made it possible was a shift from immediate rejection of a class upon noticing any issue to a mode where some problems are fatal and others result in an embedded "throw always" instruction.  This is described in some detail in http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/verifier.html .

Comment: Beyond using reflection, is there a way to suppress the log warning?

Comment: So other than using reflection or inner classes, is there a way to suppress the log message?

Comment: @scottt: You could go "old school" and isolate the new-API stuff in a dedicated class (e.g., the `HoneycombHelper` pattern). So long as you only reference this class from inside a Java version guard block (the `if` test on `SDK_INT`), it will only ever get loaded on a device with the proper SDK level. That should result in getting rid of the warning, at the cost of this additional class and a bunch of static methods on it. It has the side benefit of making you more compatible with Android 1.x. Frankly, IMHO, it's not worth it.

Comment: Thanks. The call in question is a single WebView setting method(), so isolating it isn't worth the aggravation. The purist in me would like to excise all non-exception warnings and errors from the log, but I can let this one go (along with the "error opening trace file" one).